# Checkout only the directory structure

Tags: directory, structure, cvs, vcs-checkout

How can I checkout only the directory structure of a project (without any files) in a CVS repository? This could be useful, e.g. to know the structure itself, and selectively checkout the folders later. I might not be interested in, say, the test cases folder which might take too much space on my local hard disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only to know the structure itself, you can use `cvs rls -R` which lists recursively contents of the repository. From this output, you can filter out files and get directory hierarchy.

Comment: Perhaps you meant "cvs ls -R"?

Comment: ls works with working copy, whereas rls works directly with repository.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a useful thing, might not the solution you seek. :) [TortoiseCVS](http://www.tortoisecvs.org/) can show the structure without checking out the files.

Comment: Yes but I would like to be able to export/ copy the structure in some text form. UI is good for viewing but bad for scripting.